# Update multiple rows using multiple tables in a join

Tags: sql-server

I need to update two rows and I need to use an update. All I have tried has failed.

I got the joins and select statements to work but they do not work in the Update statement.

```
Select [Order Details].ProductID
From [Order Details] Inner Join Products
On [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID
Inner join Categories
On Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
Where CategoryName = 'Confections' and Unitsinstock > 50
Group By [Order Details].ProductID
```

This statement found what I needed to update but when I used it, it would not work.

```
Begin Transaction
Go
Update [Order Details]
Set Discount = (SELECT Max(Discount))
FROM [Order Details] 
Right Join Products
    On [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID
    Inner join Categories
        On Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
        Where CategoryName = 'Confections' and Unitsinstock > 50
Group By [Order Details].ProductID
Go
RollBack Transaction
```

I am using the Roll Back just incase I mess up.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a closing paren ")" in your sample code. An error message would also be helpful.

Comment: Group by, as you are using it here, does not make sense in an update statement.

Comment: I used the group by in the select statement because it returned the same information multiple times. To stop the duplicates I used Group By.

Comment: Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Jeremy Cook I tried using subqueries until I realized that it can only be one and I need to update two.

Comment: Look into using a sub-query that returns Max(Discount) and ProductId and then join that sub-query to your [Order Details].

Comment: @JeremyCook What do you mean? The Max Discount is the update for the two unknown.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this, but it should get you what you need.

```
Update [Order Details]
Set Discount = DiscountsPerProduct.MaxDiscount
      --select OD.Discount, DiscountsPerProduct.MaxDiscount, *
From [Order Details] OD
Inner Join (
    Select Max([Order Details].Discount) as MaxDiscount, [Order Details].ProductID
    From [Order Details] 
    Inner Join Products On Products.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID
    Inner join Categories On Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
    Where CategoryName = 'Confections' and Unitsinstock > 50
    Group By [Order Details].ProductID
) DiscountsPerProduct On OD.ProductID = DiscountsPerProduct.ProductID
```

I added out the commented out select because this lets you see exactly what will be affected by the update and is useful for troubleshooting when the query is not yet correct.

Comment: This gave me my first answer, 28 rows affected.

Comment: Um, you only have one question...?

Comment: I have tried variations of each of the codes and the first one I ran gave me this solution. So I tried to change it the best I could but all of them failed. I just need two of the items to change to the max discount but instead 28 rows were affected instead of only two.

Comment: If you only need two rows to change why don't you just query the maxes and manually update the two you need to change? [Order Details] does have a primary key, right? At this point you are in the nitty-gritty details of your own database structure and data. You're on your own.